# Strings: Making Anagrams

Tags: c#

Sample Input:
`string a = "cde"`
`string b = "abc"`

Sample Output:
`4`
How is this algorithm working, why does `rez+=Math.abs(dic[c] -dic2[c])` return the correct result. I think it is using ascii but, I still do not understand how it works.

Thanks for the help

```
string a = Console.ReadLine();
string b = Console.ReadLine();

//HashSet, we have a simple syntax for taking the union of elements in a set
HashSet<char> hashset = new HashSet<char>();

foreach(char c in a )
{
    hashset.Add(c);
}
foreach (char c in b)
{
    hashset.Add(c);
}

Dictionary<char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();
Dictionary<char, int> dic2 = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach(char c in hashset)
{
    dic.Add(c, 0);
    dic2.Add(c, 0);
}

foreach(char c in a)
{
    dic[c]++;
}
foreach (char c in b)
{
    dic2[c]++;
}

int rez = 0;
foreach(char c in hashset)
{
    rez += Math.Abs(dic[c] - dic2[c]);
}
Console.WriteLine(rez);
```

Comment: You're asking *how* it works, but *does* this code even work?

Comment: Put breakpoints on the key points and use the debugger to step through the code. I don't really get what it's meant to do. Right now it just tells you how many characters are distinct between the two strings. In your example `c` is in both so is not counted, the remaining 4 characters are distinct hence the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a HashSet does not store duplicates, so if you have two times the same characters (for `a` and `b`) it only will store them once.

Example:

```
string a = "abc";
string b = "cba";
```

if you add both of them to the hashset(which you are doing in your first to foreach loops)
the hashset only contains three Characters( `a`, `b`, `c`)

In your two dictionaries you store each unique letter, and how often it appears in the two strings.
The first dictionary for `string a` and the second for `string b`

```
 foreach(char c in a)
 {
    dic[c]++;
 }

 foreach (char c in b)
 {
    dic2[c]++;
 }
```

Here you are increasing the counters for every unique char in both strings `a` and `b`
So for `dic` you are increasing every counter for every character which appears in `string a`
And for `dic2` you are increasing every counter for every character appearing in `string b`

So you are counting the number of appearences for the characters in the different strings but you are not caring about the order(which makes it an **anagram**)

Finally to see if it is a anagram or not you are substracting the (positive) differences for every unique character.

```
int rez = 0;
foreach(char c in hashset)
{
   rez += Math.Abs(dic[c] - dic2[c]);
}
```

So for your example strings of `"cde"` and `"abc"` you have six letters
where 2 of them appear in both strings one time, so you have differences in **4 letters** and they appear once every time, which makes up to a sum(`rez`) of **4**

calculation example:
dic:

```
{[c, 1]}
{[d, 1]}
{[e, 1]}
{[a, 0]}
{[b, 0]}
```

dic2:

```
{[c, 1]}
{[d, 0]}
{[e, 0]}
{[a, 1]}
{[b, 1]}
```

Now if you calculate for every character:

```
dic[c] - dic2[c] =  0
dic[d] - dic2[d] =  1
dic[e] - dic2[e] =  1
dic[a] - dic2[a] = -1
dic[b] - dic2[b] = -1
```

Now as you only take the absolute value of every result you get a sum of **4**

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i thought it was subtracting the ASCII values and couldn't understand why it was getting 4.